# Assigning a random entry from an array

Tags: c

New to C here. I am trying to initialize a a string with a random selection from an array. I have hit a roadblock. Here is what I have so far and there may be a much better way to do this.

I am trying to essentially display a random card (rank and suit, kC = King of Clubs) each run.

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()

{
char rank[13] = {'a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k'};
char suit[4] = {'C','D','H','S'};
int first;
int second;

srand(time(NULL));

                first = rand()%rank;
                second = rand()%suit;

        printf("Your Card: %d %d", first, second);


return 0;
```

I suspect that *rand* can't randomize an array like I am trying but is there a way to tell *rand* to choose from my array?
Thanks

Comment: Use `rand` to choose a random index and then use that to index the array.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>

int main()
{
    char rank[13] = {'a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k'};
    char suit[4] = {'C','D','H','S'};
    int first;
    int second;

    srand(time(NULL));

    first = rand() % 13;
    second = rand() % 4;

    printf("Your Card: %c %c", rank[first], suit[second]);

    return 0;
}
```

Comment: Note that using `%` can introduce a bias - for example with a typical value of `RAND_MAX` of `2147483647`, this code will select Queen and King slightly less frequently than the other ranks.

Answer (score 0):

`%` only works for numbers. So, you can `%` by the sizes of each array to get an index, then index into the array:

```
first = rank[rand()%13];
second = suit[rand()%4];
```

Answer (score 0):

```
#include <stdio.h>
#include <time.h>
#include <string.h>
#include <stdlib.h>

int main()

{
char rank[13] = {'a','2','3','4','5','6','7','8','9','t','j','q','k'};
char suit[4] = {'C','D','H','S'};
int first;
int second;

srand(time(NULL));

                first = rank[(rand()%13)];
                second = suit[rand()%4];

        printf("Your Card: %c %c", first, second);


return 0;
}
```

In your `printf` statement, you need to use `%c` instead of `%d` since `rank` and `suit` are arrays of characters.